# How can I make this with react-native-chart-kit

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-chart-kit

can any one help me with this. I want to create a graph similar to the one in this Picture. I have searched alot and came across this awsome library react-native-chart-kit. It is easy to make bar chart like this with this library but as you can see in the picture **only one item is high lighted and rest of the items are faded how can I do that?**

```
const data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [20, 45, 28, 80, 99, 43]
    }
  ]
};
    <BarChart
  style={graphStyle}
  data={data}
  width={screenWidth}
  height={220}
  yAxisLabel="$"
  chartConfig={chartConfig}
  verticalLabelRotation={30}
/>
```

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: Can you share the code? so its easy for the other dev to help you.

Comment: @MUHAMMADILYAS I have added the code can you look into it now?